# Data from column as IF condition and value

Tags: php

This is an odd one. I'm trying to use data from a column as an operator and value. It's possible that I could separate the condition and value (for better data type usage), but my issue would remain.

> Column 1 Data: 50, 3, 70, 2
>
> Column 2 Data: < 1, >= 5, <= 7,  > 1

I'd like to construct an IF statement that looks like this:

```
if ($column1 >= 5){} -Where >=5 is from column 2.
```

The condition and value would come from the column above. Is this even possible?

Comment: Absolutely unclear. Where columns came from?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail. The columns come from MySQL, I opted not to post that part.

Answer (score 0):

The sane solution is to create a simple parser/evaluation engine. E.g.:

```
$var1 = '50';
$var2 = '< 1';

if (!preg_match('/(\w+)\s*(\d+)/', $var2, $operands)) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid expression '$var2'");
}

switch ($operands[1]) {
    case '<' :
        return $var1 < $operands[2];
    case '<=' :
        return $var1 <= $operands[2];
    ...
    default :
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unsupported operator '$operands[1]'");
}
```

Also see whether this may already fit your needs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/introduction.html#how-can-the-expression-engine-help-me

Comment: Wow, this is a great idea. Thanks for helping. Wonderful direction.